# How to get chat history of Telegram using node-telegram-bot?

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I am developing a telegram chatbot using [node-telegram-bot](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api) in Node.js that requires getting the previous messages or chat history of user and bot.

I tried using `bot.getChat(chatId)` method but it returns the following response

```
{
  id: ,
  first_name: 'R',
  last_name: 'S',
  type: 'private',
  has_private_forwards: true
}
```

index.js

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
require('dotenv').config();
const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;
const bot = new TelegramBot(TOKEN, { polling: true });

let chat = await bot.getChat(chatid)
console.log(chat)
```

I didn't find anything else that will help me retrieve the chat logs. I created a telegram application to use Telegram Core API but it is very complicated to understand to implement the bot using this.

Any advice or ideas to retrieve the chat logs?

Comment: I would like an answer about this too... :)

Comment: I found a workaround where I created a MongoDB collection to the chats of each individual user which served as a chatlog